# Is possible to define the parity by a universal property?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Consider the parity homomorphism of the symmetric group 
$$
p:S_n\to Z/(2).
$$
Is it possible to characterise this map by a pure universal property?

This question occurred to me when I was reading this post [Is there a "natural" / "categorical" definition of the "parity" of a permutation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765663/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. It's the abelianization; that is, it's universal with respect to maps from $S_n$ into abelian groups.

Comment: Note that there is no issue with identifying the abelianization with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$; this identification requires no choices because $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has no nontrivial automorphisms. It is in fact the unique nontrivial group with this property.

Comment: We need $n \geq 2$ (otherwise $S_n$ and hence its abelianization is trivial).

Comment: @Martin: but in that case so is the parity map. That seems fine to me.

Comment: No, the abelianization is surjective.

Comment: @Martin: I don't understand why you're arguing this. It doesn't seem to make any conceivable difference to me whether the parity map for $S_1$ is regarded as a map $S_1 \to S_1/[S_1, S_1]$ or as a map $S_1 \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The codomains are different (hence the morphisms differ).

Comment: @Martin: okay, sure, obviously I know that, but is that difference important for anything? I can't think of any reason why I would really want parities for $S_1$ to take values in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.